# UNIX commands - find

Tags: command-line, find

I'm trying to learn UNIX commands and I'm playing this game to learn and I'm really stuck at the moment. I'm in a server through ssh and the directory is full of random files and folders and the password for the next level is inside one of the files. I have been told that the file has the following attrbutes:

- human-readable
- 1033 bytes
- non-executable

I am guessing that I should use the `find` command and I tried `find ! -executable` but that returned a load of files. The only human-readable help I can find in the manual or online is printing out the file sizes in human readable. So I'm a bit lost there?

Also I did try `find ~ -size 1033b` but that returned nothing. But when I tried `find ~ -size -1033b` it returned every file in the directory.

Comment: I would really like to know more about this game!

Comment: @ivanivan bandit.overthewire.org

Answer (score 20):

To filter out the human-readable file names, you can make use of the `[:print:]` (*printable*) **character class** name. You will find more about such classes in the manual for `grep`.

```
find . -type f -size 1033c -name "[[:print:]]*" ! -executable
```

---

On a second thought, the "human-readable" requirement might refer to the file's content, instead of its name. In other words, you would be searching for *text* files. That is a little more tricky. As @D_Bye suggested in a comment, you should then use the `file` command to determine the file content type. But it would not be a good idea to run `file` after a pipe, because it would complicate the task of displaying the file's name. Here's what I suggest:

```
find . -type f -size 1033c ! -executable -exec sh -c 'file -b $0 | grep -q text' {} \; -print
```

This is briefly how the `file`-part works:

- The **`-exec`** predicate executes `sh -c 'file -b $0 | grep -q text' FILENAME` for each `FILENAME` that satisfies all the previous conditions (type, size, non-executable).
- For each of those files, a shell (`sh`) runs this short **script**: `file -b $0 | grep -q text`, replacing `$0` with the filename.
- The **`file`** program determines the content type of each file and outputs this information. The `-b` option prevents printing the name of each tested file.
- **`grep`** filters the output coming from `file` program, searching for lines containing *"text"*. (See for yourself, how a typical output of the `file` command looks like.)
- But `grep` does not output the filtered text, because it has the **`-q`** (quiet) option given. What it does, is just change its *exit status* to either `0` (which represents "true" - the filtered text was found) or 1 (meaning "error" - the text *"text"* did not appear in the output from `file`).
- The true/false exit status coming from `grep` is passed further by `sh` to `find` and acts as the final result of the whole "`-exec sh -c 'file $0 | grep -q text' {} \;`" test.
- In case the above test returned *true*, the `-print` command is executed (i.e. the name of the tested file is printed).

Comment: I know this is old but I want to add that using `find . -type f -size 1033c` will also return the exact same response.

Answer (score 8):

```
find . -type f -readable -size 1033c ! -executable
```

Note that I used `c` instead of `b` for the file size.  `b` is for 512 byte blocks.  `c` is for actual bytes.

Comment: I don't think `-readable` means human-readable (i.e. not binary)

Comment: @hhaamu - right. However, it's probably not bad to filter out files the user has no rights to read! In order to determine if a file contains human-readable content, pipe the names returned by `find` to `file`.

Answer (score 2):

all I wrote was:

```
find -size 1033c ! -executable
```

and got the file. Apparently the human readable part was to throw you off.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -readable -size 1033c \! -executable
```

Comment: -readable means that the files can be read by the account, that doesn't make them necessarily human readable.

Answer (score 0):

I think for the game however the correct syntax is:

```
file ./*
```

You get a return that lists what each file is consisted of.  It worked really well for what you are trying to accomplish in the Bandit game.  The real curve ball for this task is that each file begins with - (hyphen).

Comment: You could improve upon this by adding a hyphen into that command like `file ./-*` this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best actual answer that would cover all 3 conditions

```
find inhere/ -type f -size 1033c ! -executable |xargs file | grep text
```

But as many people said, the executable and human readable were to throw us off,
so using

```
find inhere/ -type f -size 1033c
```

is quite enough !